# In React, what is the proper way to create a new instance of a component?

Tags: reactjs

Currently, I do it by assigning the `key` property, which holds a `useState` value, to a component. And whenever I need to create a new instance of this component, I just change the `useState` value.

Is this the proper way to do it? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, `key` is the correct way to force a child component to remount (assuming you can't just change to a different type of component). This is not a common thing to do, but when it's needed, that's the right way.

Comment: ...but you also need to evaluate why you need that and whether you can convert component with inner state into fully controlled(lifting its state up) to get full control over it.  Sometimes there are no other choice that use `key`(say, if there is a wrapper around non-react library), but if there is a choice - refactoring is a better way

Answer (score 0):

"Keys only make sense in the context of the surrounding array." You don't need to assign keys to a component out of this scope.
[https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#:~:text=Keys%20only%20make%20sense%20in%20the%20context%20of%20the%20surrounding%20array](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#:%7E:text=Keys%20only%20make%20sense%20in%20the%20context%20of%20the%20surrounding%20array).

Comment: that's not accurate, I understand why docs may be misleading here but "resetting state key technique" is here for years. And look, react official docs also consider this: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#:~:text=In%20order%20to%20reset%20the%20value%20when%20moving%20to%20a%20different%20item%20(as%20in%20our%20password%20manager%20scenario)%2C%20we%20can%20use%20the%20special%20React%20attribute%20called%20key.

Comment: Section you refer to say "only set `key` in the same component where you have array traversing; setting `key` somewhere inside of extracted component will not work as is indented". Just a paragraph below.